# What does `[< >]` mean in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, camlp4

I have seen some source code having

```
let rec parse_document = parser
    | [< len = parse_int32; st; >] ->
      parse_list [] (ES.take_int32 len st)
    | [< >] -> malformed "parse_document"
```

Can I know what is `[< >]` inside? it is too hard to google about this kind of signs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a syntactic sugar for the [Stream](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stream.html) datatype. Its manipulation is described in detail in [this chapter](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora040.html) of the book [Developping Applications with OCaml](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/).

The syntactic sugar is not built-in in the compiler, it needs to be preprocessed by the Camlp4 preprocessor. To do that, you have to add `-pp camlp4o` to your compilation command line.

Comment: what's `>>` inside `let encode_to_string = encode_to_buffer >> Buffer.contents`

Comment: It's a user-defined infix operator: `let (>>) f g = ...`. You have to check the definition, but from the names it looks like reverse function composition: `let (>>) f g = fun x -> g (f x)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a stream. It is used mainly to create parsers. But streams have been removed from OCaml and are now provided as a camlp4 extension.

Answer (score 2):

It is part of the [Stream parsing syntax extension](http://ocaml.org/tutorials/stream_expressions.html#Stream_Literals), and it means the empty stream.

Answer (score 1):

That's the literal syntax for [streams](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/tutorial-camlp4/tutorial002.html). A stream is just like a list except that only one element is available at a time and you remove the first element by reading it.

It seems primarily used for parser code. Parsers--declared with the `parser` keyword as in your example--are the functions that can "consume" elements of the stream.