# Please explain this example in the Stream docs, what is [< >] syntax?

Tags: ocaml

https://ocaml.org/api/Stream.html

> `val from : (int -> 'a option) -> 'a t`
>
> `Stream.from f` returns a stream built from the function `f`. To create a new stream element, the function `f` is called with the current stream count. The user function `f` must return either `Some <value>` for a value or `None` to specify the end of the stream.
>
> Do note that the indices passed to `f` may not start at `0` in the general case. For example, `[< '0; '1; Stream.from f >]` would call `f` the first time with count `2`.

There are two things confusing me about this example.

##### 1.

I had no luck googling for meaning of `[< ... >]` syntax. The closest I found was: https://ocaml.org/manual/lex.html#sss:keywords which just says those character sequences are keywords

`[< ... ]` seems to be used when printing, but not defining, polymorphic variants: https://ocaml.org/manual/polyvariant.html

If I paste in something like `[< '0; '1; >]` I get a syntax error.

So it's currently quite baffling to me what this example is purporting to show.

##### 2.

The example says that `[< '0; '1; Stream.from f >]` would call `f` the first time with count `2`

And I just wonder ... why? how?  I can see that `2` follows on from `'0` and `'1`, but how do those values influence starting value of `f`? (and why are they prefixed with `'`?)

Comment: it's the streams syntax which has been deprecated from the main compiler for years, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150173/what-does-mean-in-ocaml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The deprecated Stream module was built to be used with a camlp{4,5} syntactic extension that added support for the `[< ...>]`. See https://camlp5.github.io/doc/html/parsers.html for more documentation.

However, if you are not maintaining legacy code, you probably want to avoid the `Stream` module altogether and use the `Seq` module instead. In particular, `Stream` will not be part of the standard library starting with OCaml 5.0 .